# How to separate Components and containers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a requirement where I am creating a card slider(card carousel). I have split up the components into Slider and Card. Then I have one Container 'App'. The data for the cards come from redux. There is an option to refresh each card also. For now, I have fetch data, update data actions in the 'App' container. In App container, I do the following things.

1. Call fetch data action.
2. Get data as prop.
3. Map through it and pass necessary info into cards.
4. Pass these cards as children to the .
5. When a card is refreshed, I call the update data action .

So Is there any need to separate these? Or the current structure is fine?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import Slider from "../../Components/Slider";
import Card from "../../Components/Card";
import * as actions from "../../Store/Actions/app";


class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onInitApp(data);
  }


  cardRefreshHandler = (e, countryName, countryId) => {
    this.props.onLoading();
    this.props.onCardRefresh(country, countryId);
  };

  render() {
    let cards = "";
    if (this.props.data && this.props.data.length > 0) {
      cards = this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={index}
            id={index}
            data={item}
            onRefresh={this.cardRefreshHandler}
          />
        );
      });
    }

    return (
      <div class="app-container">
        <Slider>
          {cards}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    data: state.data,
    loading: state.loading
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onInitApp: country => dispatch(actions.fetchData(country)),
    onLoading: () => dispatch(actions.loadRefreshScreen()),
    onCardRefresh: (country, countryId) => dispatch(actions.refreshData(country, countryId))
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

This article may be useful to understand better structural difference between containers and components:  https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

> You’ll find your components much easier to reuse and reason about if you divide them into two categories. I call them Container and Presentational components* but I also heard Fat and Skinny, Smart and Dumb, Stateful and Pure, Screens and Components, etc. These all are not exactly the same, but the core idea is similar.

Comment: I tried to separate based on the article..then my 'card'  will have a container where it gets the data and refresh the data. But then I have to pass the CardContainer to the slider Presentational component. Is this a good approach? Also for the Slider to work correctly, I need to pass items directly. Not as a container which again holds a set of cards